# Html 5 "tel:"not working using eval

Tags: html

I fill the repeater with phone numbers to make calls while using on mobile phones.
But it not working.

That's html;

```
<a href="tel:"> <p style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; margin-top: 36px; font-weight: 500; color: #8b8383"><%#Eval("Telefon") %></p></a>
```

How can i solve this? Thanks..

Comment: You need to set the phone number after `tel:` also? like this: `<a href="tel:012345678"><p>012345678</p></a>`

Comment: @SebastianBrosch , this worked at iphone but not working android phones. Do you know how fixed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the value in the href attribute too:

```
<a href="tel:<%#Eval("Telefon") %>"> <p style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; margin-top: 36px; font-weight: 500; color: #8b8383"><%#Eval("Telefon") %></p></a>
```

Comment: Hi,  this worked at iphone but not working android phones. Do you know how fixed it?